# Label histogram by bins matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bins

I have a histogram in which I want to label the x-axis by bins. The histogram is plotted as a log log graph, but the bins are very specific. The graph:

[image: The Graph]

The bins:

```
bins = [0, 0.035, 0.07, 0.15, 0.5, 1, 3, 10, 40]
```

Is there any way I can do this? I believe it would also require getting rid of the current x-axis labels.

Comment: What about `ax.set_xticks(bins)`? Also, I think it would look better if you added the paramater `edgecolor="k"` in your `plt.hist`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote an example code for you. Basically, all you need was 'set_xticks' and 'set_xticklabels'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 18, 18, 18]
my_bins = [0.001, 0.035, 0.07, 0.15, 0.5, 1, 3, 10, 40]

ind = np.array(my_bins[:-1])
width = np.array([my_bins[i+1]-my_bins[i] for i in range(len(my_bins)-1)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.hist(x, bins=my_bins)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('bin1', 'bin2', 'bin3', 'bin4', 'bin5', 'bin6', 'bin7', 'bin8'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: That worked, except my labels are slightly misaligned with the bins. :)

Comment: Great! I think you can adjust the xticks to align your labels. This can be done by modifying the 'ind' and 'width' array.

Comment: sorry if im asking an obvious question but how would i adjust these arrays to make the labels go slightly left?

Comment: If you try to print the content of 'ind+width/2', you will see a list. Each value in this list stands for the position where you want to show your labels along x-axis. I show the label in the center of each bin.

Comment: ok that helps. thanks!