# matplotlib: Setting x tick label on the bar plot to be a range of price

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

have original bins on a plot  = array([     0,   2500,   5000,   7500,  10000,  12500,  15000,  17500,
        20000,  22500,  25000,  27500,  30000,  32500,  35000,  37500,
        40000,  42500,  45000,  47500,  50000,  52500,  55000,  57500,
        60000,  62500,  65000,  67500,  70000,  72500,  75000,  77500,
        80000,  82500,  85000,  87500,  90000,  92500,  95000,  97500,
       100000, 102500], dtype=int64)

which looks like [image]

would like to have x tick label displayed in a range and in price format(such as *$0-$2,500*, *$2,500-$50,000*, etc..). Something like below but with $ sign before each number  [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MatPlotLib Dollar Sign with Thousands Comma Tick Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152356/matplotlib-dollar-sign-with-thousands-comma-tick-labels)

Comment: @Bazingaa no I need a range of the price displayed in each label/position, the link you sent only has one price per position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the difference from the dupe. I would present a workaround solution using a sample data since you did not provide a MCVE

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.hist(np.random.normal(50000, 10000, 100000), bins=bins)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100000)

fig.canvas.draw()
labels = [i.get_text().strip('$') for i in ax.get_xticklabels()]
new_labels = [('\${:,}' + 'to' +  '\${:,}').format(int(i), int(j)) 
              for i, j in zip(labels[0:-1],labels[1:])]

ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas's `cut` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)) and numpy’s [linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) (or anything equivalent), it should be possible to generate both the intervals bins ( n bins) and corresponding bins labels (n-1). You can use the $ sign to enrich those bins labels.
See also [Label histogram by bins matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228265/label-histogram-by-bins-matplotlib)

Adapted example using seaborn:

[image]

```
# coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(5000, 1000, 1000)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataframe = dataframe.rename({0 : 'values'}, axis='columns')
print(dataframe.head(3))
print('---------------')
cut_vals = np.linspace(start=dataframe['values'].min(),stop=dataframe['values'].max(),num=8)
bin_headers = list()

for index in range(len(cut_vals) - 1):
    header = '$ {}-{}'.format(int(cut_vals[index]), int(cut_vals[index+1]))
    bin_headers.append(header)

print(bin_headers)

print('---------------')
dataframe['categories'] = pd.cut(dataframe['values'], cut_vals, labels=bin_headers)

print('---------------')
print(dataframe.head(2))

ind = np.array(cut_vals[:-1])
width = np.array([cut_vals[i+1]-cut_vals[i] for i in range(len(cut_vals)-1)])

g = sns.distplot(dataframe['values'], bins=cut_vals, label='foo')
g.set_xticks(ind + width/2)
g.set_xticklabels(bin_headers, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
        values
0  4442.338053
1  5253.443608
2  6552.700087
---------------
['$ 2080-3034', '$ 3034-3988', '$ 3988-4942', '$ 4942-5897', '$ 5897-6851', '$ 6851-7805', '$ 7805-8759']
---------------
---------------
        values   categories
0  4442.338053  $ 3988-4942
1  5253.443608  $ 4942-5897
```